# Ubuntu LiveCD customization : keep services stopped at startup

Tags: startup, live-cd, services

I'm customizing Ubuntu 11.10 LiveCD.

I added Apache, MySQL (and PHP), but the apache & mysql services start on Ubuntu startup.

I want to keep these services stopped (users will have to launch them when needed). How to to so? Before rebuilding the ISO image, I deleted startup script with update-rc.d, no success!

By the way, is there a GUI for starting / stopping easily services?

Answer (score 3):

> is there a GUI for starting / stopping easily services?

Yes, install `rcconf` (text user interface, though).

If you are `chroot`ed into the LiveCD squashfs, `rcconf` will help you disable thoe services on startup too.